Proof that $\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \binom{n}{i+1} \binom{n-i-1}{i} < \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{i}$
I'm hoping to prove (or cite a proof of) the following inequality:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \binom{n}{i+1} \binom{n-i-1}{i}  < \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{i}$$
for all even $n$ greater than or equal to 8. I don't necessarily need the odd $n$ case (though it does seem to hold for odd $n \geq 13$).
One of the many ways to rewrite this identity is to use trinomial coefficients:
$$ \binom{n}{0}_2 - \binom{n}{1}_2 > \binom{n}{n/2}$$
where $\binom{n}{k}_2$ is the coefficient of $t^{n+k}$ in $(1 + t + t^2)^n$.  The left hand side of this version of the inequality is the $n^{th}$ Riordan number.
Here are a few things my collaborators and I have tried, in case one sparks an idea:

applying identities for trinomial coefficients,
rewriting in terms of ratios of gamma functions,
rewriting as Gegenbauer polynomials,
looking for nice expressions for how the sums increase when $n$ increases in hopes of proving this inductively,
looking for a proper subset of the objects counted by the $n^{th}$ Riordan number that could be counted by $\binom{n}{n/2}$,
induction using the defining recurrence relation for Riordan numbers.


The left side counts ordered partitions $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$ of ${1,\dots,n}$ with $|A_1|=|A_2|+1,$ while the right side counts the partitions with $|A_1|=|A_2|$ and $A_3\neq\emptyset.$ Not sure if that helps. Not sure if that helps.

Seeking to prove that
$$\sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q+1} {n-q-1\choose q}
\lt \sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q} {n-q\choose q}$$
we get for the LHS
$$A_n = \sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q+1} {n-q-1\choose q}
\\ = \sum_{q\ge 1} {n\choose q} {n-q\choose q-1}
= \sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q} {n-q\choose n+1-2q}
\\ = [z^{n+1}] (1+z)^n \sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q}
\frac{z^{2q}}{(1+z)^q}
\\ = [z^{n+1}] (1+z)^n
\left[1+\frac{z^2}{1+z}\right]^n
= [z^{n+1}] [1+z+z^2]^n.$$
On the other hand the RHS is
$$B_n = \sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q} {n-q\choose q}
= \sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q} {n-q\choose n-2q}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^n \sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q}
\frac{z^{2q}}{(1+z)^q}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^n
\left[1+\frac{z^2}{1+z}\right]^n
= [z^n] [1+z+z^2]^n.$$
We then have
$$B_n - A_n = [z^{n+1}] (z-1) [1+z+z^2]^n
= - [z^{n+1}] \frac{(1-z^3)^n}{(1-z)^{n-1}}
\\ = - \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/3\rfloor} [z^{3q}] (1-z^3)^n 
[z^{n+1-3q}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-1}}
\\ = - \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/3\rfloor} [z^q] (1-z)^n 
{2n-1-3q\choose n-2}
\\ = - \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/3\rfloor}
{n\choose q} (-1)^q {2n-1-3q\choose n+1-3q}.$$
Here the second binomial coefficient enforces the upper
range and we get
$$- [z^{n+1}] (1+z)^{2n-1} 
\sum_{q\ge 0} {n\choose q} (-1)^q
\frac{z^{3q}}{(1+z)^{3q}}
\\ = - [z^{n+1}] (1+z)^{2n-1} 
[1-z^3/(1+z)^3]^n
\\ = - [z^{n+1}] \frac{1}{(1+z)^{n+1}} (1+3z+3z^2)^n.$$
This is
$$-\;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^{n+2}} \frac{1}{(1+z)^{n+1}} (1+3z+3z^2)^n.$$
Now put $z=(-1+\sqrt{1+4w})/2$ so that $z(1+z)=w$ and $dz = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4w}} \; dw$ and $z^2 = w-z$ to get
$$-\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n+2}} \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4w}}{2}
(1+3w)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4w}}
\\ = -\frac{1}{2} \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n+2}} (1+3w)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4w}}.$$
Next  put $w/(1+3w)=v$  to get  $w=v/(1-3v)$ and  $dw =
1/(1-3v)^2 \; dv$ to obtain
$$-\frac{1}{2} \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{n+2}} (1-3v)^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4v/(1-3v)}}
\frac{1}{(1-3v)^2}.$$
Our desired quantity is thus
$$F_n = -\frac{1}{2} [v^{n+1}] \sqrt{\frac{1-3v}{1+v}}.$$
Note that
$$\left(-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1-3v}{1+v}}\right)'
= \sqrt{\frac{1-3v}{1+v}} \frac{1}{1-3v} \frac{1}{1+v}$$
or alternatively
$$(1-2v-3v^2)
\left(-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1-3v}{1+v}}\right)'
= \sqrt{\frac{1-3v}{1+v}}.$$
Extracting the coefficient on $[v^n]$ yields
$$(n+1) F_n - 2 n F_{n-1} - 3 (n-1) F_{n-2} = (-2) F_{n-1}.$$
This will produce the recurrence where $n\ge 2$
$$F_n = \frac{n-1}{n+1} (2 F_{n-1} + 3 F_{n-2}).$$
This means that  as soon as two  positive values appear
the remainder of  the sequence will be  positive and we
have our claim that $F_n\gt  0$ or $B_n\gt A_n.$ Taking
$F_2  = F_3  = 1$  will  do (values  computed from  the
definition of $A_n$ and $B_n$).
This computation made extensive use of
OEIS A005043.
 Addendum, asymptotics 
To  compute  the  asymptotics  of $F_n$  we  may  apply
Darboux' lemma as documented in Theorem 5.3.1 of Wilf's
generatingfunctionology  (page 179).   To do  this we
re-write as follows:
$$F_n = -\frac{1}{2} 3^{n+1}
[v^{n+1}] \sqrt{\frac{1-v}{1+v/3}}.$$
The lemma then says that we can expand $1/\sqrt{1+v/3}$
as  a series  in  $1-v,$ multiply  by $\sqrt{1-v}$  and
extract the coefficient on  $n+1$ to get the asymptotic
expansion.  Here the  first  term  will suffice,  which
gives a contribution of $1/\sqrt{4/3} = \sqrt{3}/2.$
We get
$$-\frac1{4} 3^{n+3/2} [v^{n+1}] \sqrt{1-v}
= -\frac1{4} 3^{n+3/2} (-1)^{n+1} {1/2\choose n+1}
\\ = -\frac1{8} 3^{n+3/2} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n+1}
{-1/2\choose n}
\\ = \frac1{8} 3^{n+3/2} \frac{1}{n+1}
{2n\choose n} 4^{-n}.$$
The asymptotics of the central binomial coefficient are
classic,   being   given   by   ${2n\choose   n}   \sim
\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ so that we find
$$\frac1{8} 3^{n+3/2} \frac{1}{n+1}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
\sim \frac{3^{n+3/2}}{8\sqrt\pi n^{3/2}}.$$
OP also  asked about the relation  to ${n\choose n/2}.$
We get  $2^n/\sqrt{\pi n/2} =  2^{n+1/2}/\sqrt{\pi n}.$
For the ratio we obtain
$$(3/2)^{n+1/2} \times \frac{3}{8}
\times \frac{1}{n+1}.$$
It  follows  that $F_n  \gt  {n\choose  n/2}$, with  an
initial  segment  of  seven values  where  the  inverse
$1/(n+1)$  dominates  which   is  outperformed  by  the
exponential term $(3/2)^{n+1/2}$ thereafter.

Very thorough, thank you! In thinking about it in the days after posting, I had gone in a similar direction, but was taking the recurrence relation for the Riordan numbers ($F_n$ above) on faith from the OEIS---it's really nice to see where that recurrence comes from.

In my usual simple minded way,
I am going to compare
the corresponding terms
on the two sides.
It turns out that the right side terms
are greater about 1/3 of the time
(for $n/3 < i < n/2$),
so this doesn't help much.
However,
in the hope that my
playing around
might be useful
to something else,
here is what I did.
$\begin{array}\\
d(n, i)
&=\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{i}-\binom{n}{i+1} \binom{n-i-1}{i}\\
&=\dfrac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\dfrac{(n-i)!}{i!(n-2i)!}-\dfrac{n!}{(i+1)!(n-i-1)!}\dfrac{(n-i-1)!}{i!(n-2i-1)!}\\
&=\dfrac{n!}{i!}\dfrac{1}{i!(n-2i)!}-\dfrac{n!}{(i+1)!}\dfrac{1}{i!(n-2i-1)!}\\
&=\dfrac{n!}{i!^2(n-2i-1)!}\left(\dfrac{1}{n-2i}-\dfrac{1}{i+1}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{n!}{i!^2(n-2i-1)!}\left(\dfrac{i+1-(n-2i)}{(i+1)(n-2i)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{n!}{i!^2(n-2i)!}\dfrac{3i+1-n}{(i+1)}\\
\end{array}
$
Since $i$ goes from $0$
to $n/2$,
$d(n, i) > 0$
from about $i=n/3$ to $i=n/2$
or about 1/3 of the cases.

Thank you! The fact that the terms of the smaller sum are larger most of the time is definitely the tricky thing that kept a lot of my early attempts from working.
